# Angular 2 material: sidenav toggle from another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using [Angular 2 Material](https://github.com/angular/material2) sidenav in my project this way:

`app.component.ts` (Main) html view:

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" [opened]="true">
      This is the main sidenav
      <sidebar></sidebar>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-sidenav #end align="end">
    This sidenav suppose to open from different components across my application to show extra information/data when user clicks an image for example.
    <br>
    <button md-button (click)="end.close()">Close</button>
  </md-sidenav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Now.. in order to open the `#end` sidenav I use the following button in the same component:

`<button md-button (click)="end.open()">Open End Side</button>`

But, what if I want to use `end.open()` from a different component to toggle the sidenav?
 How I am supposed to make the sidenav "gloal" so I can open it on any component in my app?

Comment: This should be using the angular-material2 tag and not angular-material tag.

Answer (score 12):

Usually a shared service is used for this.

Provide the service at a common ancestor. The component that controls the open status injects the service and the components that want to request the controlling component to change the status also inject the service.

When some component wants the sidenav to toggle, they send an event using the shared service. The component controlling the toggle listens for events and toggles on request.

For more details see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Should a service be used here or @ViewChild like the second answer?

Comment: `@ViewChild` requires the target to be a child of the current component. A service works across the whole application.

Answer (score 3):

Use @ViewChild from your parent component, and pass it to component who you'd like to access sidenav methods (open, close toggle) from.

ref: https://yakovfain.com/2016/04/19/angular-2-exposing-child-components-api/

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('start') start:MdSidenav;
}
```